# Can not inject the datepicker module using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I am getting the following error while injecting the angular-datepicker module using angular.js.

> Error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=Channabasavashwara&…0at%20d%20(http%3A%2F%2Foditek.in%2FGofasto%2Fjs%2Fangularjs.js%3A19%3A463)
```

I am explaining my code below.

> plan.html:

```
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
    <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Date :</span>
    <datepicker date-format="MMMM d, y" date-min-limit="2010/01/01" date-max-limit="2020/01/01"button-prev='<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i>' button-next='<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>'> 
        <input type="text" name="birthdate" class="form-control" ng-model="date" placeholder="Add date" />
    </datepicker>
</div>
```

The controller file contains the below code.

```
var plan=angular.module('Channabasavashwara',['Channabasavashwara.datepicker']);
plan.controller('planController',function($scope,$http,$state){     
});
```

In this app i am using `ui-router` for view.I also need here after coming the calender when user will choose the date the date will visible in that textfield so that user can retrieve the value.Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: does `Channabasavashwara.datepicker` is defined? isn't that relevant Javascript file is included?

Comment: @PankajParkar: i was following [this site](https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker).I have also included the required js/css file which has explained here.

Comment: shouldn't the dependency be '720kb.datepicker'? var plan=angular.module('Channabasavashwara',['720kb.datepicker']);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of :

```
angular.module('Channabasavashwara', ['Channabasavashwara.datepicker']);
```

You must have:

```
angular.module('Channabasavashwara', ['720kb.datepicker']);
```

In the [documentation](https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker) of the module, `'720kb.datepicker'` is not some random name. It is the exact name of the module, and you have to use that exact name in the module dependencies array.

Comment: @ Michael : Ok, error has gone but the partial view is not coming after including this module.

Comment: Do you have `ng-app="Channabasavashwara"` in the template? That's not visible in the description of the question.

Comment: Yes,I have when i am removing this module its working properly.BTW i have not mentioned all of the code in my post.I am using `ui-router` for render the view.

Comment: Then you have also `ui.router` in the array of dependencies don't you? Can you reproduce your problem in a plunker? It would be really easier to help.

Comment: I think you might have redefined your app declaration. You should only use module with the second parameter only once in your whole project. If you have more dependencies, just append them to the first declaration. Example: `angular.module('Channabasavashwara', ['ui.router', '720kb.datepicker']);`

Comment: I did it it will include inside the ui-roter path set file.